# Running progress within QGIS plugin which was created in the Qt Designer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, gui, qt-designer, progress

I am trying to run my plugin with a progress bar. The progress bar I have added was created in Qt designer and looks like this:

[image]

The name of the bar in Qt designer is "progressBar" and I have set the value there to 0.

So far I have this:

```py
def progressbar(self):
  
        # setting for loop to set value of progress bar
        for i in range(101):
  
            # slowing down the loop
            time.sleep(0.05)
  
            # setting value to progress bar
            self.pbar.setValue(i)
```

However, I do not know how to connect my plugin from the Qt designer to this to make it run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to have: `self.progressBar.reset()` at the start of my processing
And then define the percentage after each processing step with `self.progressBar.setValue(5)` (e.g. processing bar is at 5% after the first step) then `self.progressBar.setValue(15)` (e.g. processing bar is at 15% after the second step)... until it is at 100